# Is it possible to redirect from One Apple Watch App to Another Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I want to open Apple Default Watch app from my watch application. Like, In My watch app I have added buttons and on click, I want to open a specific watch app. Like, On button Click open Wether **Watch App, Breathe App, Stocks Watch App** and so on.

I have reviewed many URLs but not succeed. I have tried below code on Watch Interface Button but It's NOT working.

```
@IBAction func openSpecificWatchApp() {

        if let breatheURL = URL(string: "com.apple.mobilecal"){//com.apple.mobilemail //com.apple.Breathe 
            let wkEXt = WKExtension.shared()
            wkEXt.openSystemURL(breatheURL)
        }

    }
```

**1. Is it possible to redirect on specific Watch App?**

Please let us know your thoughts.

Thank You,